# PowerShell Environment Variable does not equal its string equivalent

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod

## Problem

I am unable to use an Environment Variable as a token in an Invoke-RestMethod

I have the following code, that does work:

```
$props = @{
    Uri = $my_url
    Method = "POST"
    ContentType = "application/json"
    Headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer Token123456789" }
}

$payload = Invoke-RestMethod @props
```

But I don't want the token hard-coded here.

However, if I replace `Token123456789` with the environment variable `$env:token` which contains the identical token, it fails.

```
$props = @{
    Uri = $my_url
    Method = "POST"
    ContentType = "application/json"
    Headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:token" }
}

$payload = Invoke-RestMethod @props
```

The error message is

> Invoke-RestMethod : Specified value has invalid Control characters.
>
> Parameter name: value
>
> At C:\Temp\test.ps1:29 char:12
>
> $payload = Invoke-RestMethod @props
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ArgumentException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

## What I have tried

I have tried comparing them directly, like this

```
$bearer1 = "$env:token"
$bearer2 = "Token123456789"
echo $bearer1
echo $bearer2
echo ($bearer1 -eq $bearer2)
```

The first two echo's output the same results.

However, the last one returns `False`

## Conclusion

The Environment Variable for some reason does not equal its string equivalent.

How do I turn the environment variable into this identical string so that it will work in my `Invoke-RestMethod`?

Comment: Use the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#subexpression-operator--): `"Bearer $($env:token)"`

Comment: How do you define `$env:token` ?

Comment: assuming this could be a graph API query, if you use `Get-MsalToken`, something like this should work fine: `$result = Get-MsalToken @tokenParams; $env:token = $result.CreateAuthorizationHeader()`

Comment: @iRon No, "$env:name" interpolates just fine even without subexpression.

Comment: Is "Token123456789" the literal value you are testing with or are you actually passing a different value that indeed contains special characters which might need encoding?

Comment: @iRon This unfortunately did not work

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I defined it using the setx command in command prompt
I.e. setx token Token123456789

Comment: @zett42 The token only contains alphanumeric characters and underscores

Comment: The token is constantly changing so, why do you define it in cmd? Why not define it from powershell each time you request it? it seems you're looking to make things harder than it should

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon The token is defined on the creation of a docker container. It is not constantly changing. It needs to be accessed from a script within the container after creation.

Comment: Ah my bad, assumed this was a Graph token for some reason. Ok, in that case, instead of using cmd, do it from powershell itself using `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('token', $tokenGoesHere, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)` then after restarting your process or starting a new powershell session `$env:token` should be available to you

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I don't understand why that worked, but it did. Thanks! Odd that setx would somehow be different from SetEnvironmentVariable

Comment: my guess, doing it from cmd appends an extra space, or line break or some encoding issue. hard to tell without comparing the hex from both sides. but yeah, I guess you learnt now that defaulting to cmd for something that can be done from pwsh is not a good idea, and yes 100% of the things you can do in cmd can be done in pwsh and much much more

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I checked for spaces, but couldn't find any. How could I compare the hex? And yes... I have been learning how much better powershell is overall. There's just things like setx in cmd which was shorter to type, so I didn't think anything of it.

Comment: you could try `$env:varFromPwsh | Format-Hex` and compare it with `$env:varFromSetx | Format-Hex` , maybe that can give you a hint

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon So the was somehow an invisible dot before the token when I used setx.
This was caused by a lack of quotes for some reason.
`setx token Token123456789` appended a dot.
`setx token "Token123456789"` worked without appending the dot.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for you help through this! Wouldn't have found that without you.